# Scale to selected element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have some boxes and I want to zoom it from position of the clicked box.

Here is UI . Now it will just scale from center, but I want it to scale from position of clicked element

[image: 1]

Here is my code.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  addDays,
  eachDayOfInterval,
  endOfMonth,
  format,
  getDay,
  startOfMonth,
  subDays,
} from "date-fns";
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from "framer-motion";

const getDaysOfMonth = (date) => {
  const start = startOfMonth(new Date(date));
  const end = endOfMonth(new Date(date));
  return eachDayOfInterval({ start, end });
};

const Calendar = () => {
  const [currentDate, setCurrentDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [selectedDay, setSelectedDay] = useState(null);

  console.log(selectedDay);

  const handleDayClick = (day) => {
    setSelectedDay(day);
  };

  const changeDateByDay = (numberOfDays) => {
    if (numberOfDays < 0) {
      numberOfDays = Math.abs(numberOfDays);
      setCurrentDate(subDays(currentDate, numberOfDays));
    } else {
      setCurrentDate(addDays(currentDate, numberOfDays));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="px-4 pt-10">
      <h1 className="text-center font-bold">Calendar</h1>

      <div className="text-center mb-4">
        <h2>
          Current Date: <b>{format(currentDate, "dd-LL-yyyy")}</b>
        </h2>
        <div>
          <button
            className="p-2 border m-4 "
            onClick={() => changeDateByDay(-1)}
          >
            Prev Day
          </button>
          <button
            className="p-2 border m-4 "
            onClick={() => setSelectedDay(null)}
          >
            Clear
          </button>
          <button
            className="p-2 border m-4 "
            onClick={() => changeDateByDay(1)}
          >
            Next Day
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="relative">
        <AnimatePresence>
          {selectedDay === null && (
            <motion.div
              exit={{
                scale: 6,
              }}
              transition={{
                duration: 0.8,
                ease: "easeInOut",
              }}
              className="grid grid-cols-7"
            >
              {getDaysOfMonth(currentDate).map((el, idx) => (
                <div
                  onClick={() => handleDayClick(el)}
                  className="h-16 border p-2 hover:bg-gray-100 transform"
                  key={idx}
                >
                  {format(el, "dd")}
                </div>
              ))}
            </motion.div>
          )}
        </AnimatePresence>

        {selectedDay !== null && (
          <motion.div
            initial={{
              scale: 0,
              y: 0,
            }}
            animate={{
              scale: 1,
            }}
            transition={{
              duration: 0.8,
              ease: "easeInOut",
            }}
            className="absolute top-0"
          >
            <div>
              <h2>20-2-2023</h2>
              <h1>Goinf onward</h1>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae
                placeat, rem, doloremque, tempore optio repellat architecto
                earum esse repellendus nemo tempora qui accusantium sapiente
                ullam inventore id quia explicabo dignissimos?
              </p>
            </div>
          </motion.div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Calendar;
```

Here is the ideas that I want to do https://dribbble.com/shots/10224104-Calendar-app.

I will also appreciate if you can give some ideas how to built it.

Comment: What you are showing and what you are asking is wildly different. For us to help you, you'd need to have a specific question.

Comment: Why not a ```modal``` that will render the info of that clicked box?

Comment: I just want to make a zooming effect

Comment: try to run code it will be easy to understand

Comment: also there is a link at the end, can you see that

Comment: Given the dribble example, you cannot simply use `scale` or `transform: scale(..)` as each zoom level from *month view* to *appointement detail view* shows varying element sizes and detail content. Also, this way the scaled element will be pulled out of the regular document flow and a new*stacking context* will be created. Better would be using a custom zoom factor (like custom var `--doc-zoom`) and use that to calculate relevant element size changes. Per zoom level you can use different scale factors for the varying element sizes and have them (dis)appear where needed.